# RtlQueryRegistryValues read REG_DWORD

Tags: windows, drivers, wdk

I'm writing a Uart16550 driver, and one of the things I have to do is read from the registry some initialization parameters using RtlQueryRegistryValues.

(a lot of code skipped...)

```
RTL_QUERY_REGISTRY_TABLE table[2];
```

and

```
table[1].QueryRoutine = NULL;
table[1].Name = NULL;
```

The parameter is stored in the registry as a REG_DWORD and I'm trying to set my table with:

```
unsigned long buffer;
```

(because DWORD is not defined in ntddk.h and I'm not sure if I break anything including WinDef.h)
and

```
table[0].EntryContext = &buffer;
```

The status of the call to RtlQueryRegistryValues is STATUS_SUCCESS

```
status =  RtlQueryRegistryValues(
    RTL_REGISTRY_ABSOLUTE,
    path,
    table,
    NULL,
    NULL);
```

but when I try to

```
DbgPrint("registry: %lu", buffer)
```

I get way too big numbers (I expected the result to be 1 or 2).

Am I doing something wrong with the DbgPrint, or my parameters aren't set correctly for the query table?

And where is the RED_DWORD data type defined?

EDIT:

```
WCHAR keyname[20] = "parameter";
CHAR def[20] = "parameter";
WCHAR path[100] = L"\\Registry\\Machine\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\hello\\Parameters"; 
unsigned long buffer; 
table[0].QueryRoutine = NULL; 
table[0].Name = keyname; 
table[0].Flags = RTL_QUERY_REGISTRY_DIRECT; 
table[0].EntryContext = &buffer; 
table[0].DefaultType = REG_DWORD; 
table[0].DefaultData = def; 
table[0].DefaultLength = strlen(def) + 1;
```

Comment: Is there more code missing? What are the other values for the remaining members of `table[0]`? And what is the result of `status`?

Comment: `WCHAR keyname[20] = "parameter";
CHAR def[20] = "parameter";
WCHAR path[100] = L"\\Registry\\Machine\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\hello\\Parameters";
unsigned long buffer[100];

table[0].QueryRoutine = NULL;
table[0].Name = keyname;
table[0].Flags = RTL_QUERY_REGISTRY_DIRECT;
table[0].EntryContext = buffer;
table[0].DefaultType = REG_DWORD;
table[0].DefaultData = def;
table[0].DefaultLength = strlen(def) + 1;`

and the status is STATUS_SUCCESS

    `switch(status)
    {
        case STATUS_SUCCESS:
 DbgPrint("Found the value!");
 break;`

Comment: Sorry, this is what I wrote:

`unsigned long buffer;` and `table[0].EntryContext = &buffer;`

Comment: Can you just give me some more idea about this problem(reading data from registry)?I'm facing same problem..Where value of keys stores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table[0].DefaultData` should be a pointer to an unsigned long.
`table[0].DefaultLength` should be sizeof(unsigned long).

Otherwise you may get back 1634886000 which is your default value converted to long ('para'). Everything else looks like it should work (assuming the key and value actually exists).

REG_DWORD is defined in winnt.h

```c
#define REG_DWORD                   ( 4 )   // 32-bit number
#define REG_DWORD_LITTLE_ENDIAN     ( 4 )   // 32-bit number (same as REG_DWORD)
#define REG_DWORD_BIG_ENDIAN        ( 5 )   // 32-bit number
```

Comment: That's correct. And also I should've used `L macro`:
`WCHAR keyname = L"parametru"` (Romanian name, never mind)